# TextField content checking

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield and i want to ensure the data or entry is not more than the intended value.example "the value to be entered should not be more than $4000".

i did some research but i still have been able to solve the problem.

`

```
TextFormField(
                                  
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                        RegExp(r"[0-9]+|\s"))
                                  ],
                                  controller: kiloMeter,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value != null &&
                                        value.isEmpty &&
                                        value.length < 4) {
                                      return 'Please enter the price you want to purchase';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  height: 120,
                                );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  controller: kiloMeter,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value != null && value.isEmpty && int.parse(value) > 4000) {
                                      return 'Please enter the price you want to purchase';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  height: 120,
                                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parsing in the validator to check the value

You can easily convert the string value that comes from the TextFormField to int by use `int.parse(value)`.

So your code would be:

```
TextFormField(
                                  
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                        RegExp(r"[0-9]+|\s"))
                                  ],
                                  controller: kiloMeter,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value != null &&
                                        value.isEmpty &&
                                        int.parse(value) <= 4000 {
                                      return 'Please enter the price you want to purchase';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(
                                  height: 120,
                                );
```